# JSON object with key numbers and values of recurring strings separated in to string array with count

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a json object in the below mentioned format. I need a function which will return course name and count. There is an an answer for my problem from this question. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58523404/create-multidimensional-array-of-key-value-with-key-unique-count-as-value-from) is for a different json object.  ["advanced-data-structures", 3], ["advanced-r", 3]

```
// Size of the JSON Object
  let json = {
    "0": "advanced-data-structures",
    "1": "advanced-data-structures",
    "145": "advanced-data-structures",
    "149": "advanced-excel",
    "185": "advanced-excel",
    "186": "advanced-r",
    "202": "advanced-r",
    "203": "advanced-r",
    "204": "advanced-trading-algorithms",
    "205": "advanced-trading-algorithms",
    "206": "agile-planning-for-software-products",
    "276": "agile-planning-for-software-products",
    "277": "agile-planning-for-software-products",
    "278": "algorithmic-thinking-1",
    "282": "algorithmic-thinking-1",
    "283": "algorithmic-thinking-1"
  };
  let arrayOfCourses = [];
  let count = Object.keys(json).length;
  Object.keys(json).forEach(function(prop) {
    console.log('Key Count', prop)
  });
  Object.values(json).forEach(function (prop){
    console.log('Value', prop);
    // I would need something like this
    // ["advanced-data-structures", 3],
    // ["advanced-r", 3]
  });

  for(var i = 0 ; i< count; i++) {
    console.log(json[i])
    arrayOfCourses.push(json[i]);
  }
  let uniqueItems = Array.from(new Set(arrayOfCourses))
  // unique Items removing duplicates. 
  console.log(uniqueItems)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first take Object.values of your object then reduce it on the basis of the course name:

```js
const json = { "0": "advanced-data-structures", "1": "advanced-data-structures", "145": "advanced-data-structures", "149": "advanced-excel", "185": "advanced-excel", "186": "advanced-r", "202": "advanced-r", "203": "advanced-r", "204": "advanced-trading-algorithms", "205": "advanced-trading-algorithms", "206": "agile-planning-for-software-products", "276": "agile-planning-for-software-products", "277": "agile-planning-for-software-products", "278": "algorithmic-thinking-1", "282": "algorithmic-thinking-1", "283": "algorithmic-thinking-1" };

const result = Object.entries(Object.values(json).reduce((a,e)=>{
    a[e] = a[e] || 0;
    a[e]+=1;
    return a;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

After reduce you can take `entries` of that result object.